# Django NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/ for password reset

Tags: python, django

Just another NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/ question.
I have tried so many different solutions and nothing is working for me.
BTW I get no error if I try a random password that is not in the DB.

Django 1.6

**Error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'Mg', u'token': u'3vb-60fc793f1a685844bbe1'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Error during template rendering

In template /home/jr/Documents/python/amapp1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 7
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'Mg', u'token': u'3vb-60fc793f1a685844bbe1'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, password_reset, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_done, password_reset_complete

url(r'^password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
 {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password/reset/done/'}),
url(r'^password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
 {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password/done/'}),
url(r'^password/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

**password_reset_email.html**

```
{{ protocol}}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

It is the link inside the password_reset_email.html template as I do receive the email and get no error if I remove the link.

Answer (score 3):

Change the url in your password_reset_email.html to:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

This is how it is done in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have tried both uidb36 and uidb64 as it was recommended for Django 1.6 with no success. Currently I'm not using Django Registration.

Comment: @WayBehind Sorry, I totally changed my answer. See the new answer. Try the 'password_reset_confirm' url.

Comment: Thank you for the new reply. Still the same `NoReverseMatch` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you re submit the forgot password form so a new email url was sent that contained a new token?

Comment: yes, even restarted the local server to create new session.

Comment: @WayBehind Are you upgrading from a different version of django? If so, what version?

Comment: I'm not upgrading, its a new app running on Django 1.6.4. The user registration is email based on this http://blackglasses.me/2013/10/08/custom-django-user-model-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django 1.6 as you are stating than the code you are using is wrong as password reset was changed in Django 1.6.

Please read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset

You must change the template for your password reset email accordingly.

You must also change the urls accordingly

You have now

```
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
 {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password/done/'}),
```

Should be something like this

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
```